# In Linux, what does the KVM shadow page happen if I allocate hugepages to virtual machine

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-machine

The virtualization is KVM, and I set the Linux guest OS machine page size to 4KB. Then I set the size of page allocated to the virtual machine 2MB on the host OS. Under the shadow pages machinery, the *guest OS* page table maps the **guest OS virtual address** to the **guest OS physical address**, and the *host OS* page table maps the **guest OS physical address** to the **machine address**.
But the page size is different, can the hugepages machinery achieve on the virtual machine? Or how does the hugepages mapping machinery work?
In the below image, I understand the address mapping machienry that the page size of both page table is 64KB, but I could not understand how does the machienry work when the host OS page size is 2MB(The 2MB page is allocated to the virtual machine by the host OS).
[The image of different address mapping situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjTFB.png)

I make a test to try to know what is the effect of different page size in the host OS.The guest OS page size is both 64KB, but the host OS page size is 64KB or 2MB. I use *stress* tool to load a memory stress on virtual machine and use *cyclictest* tool to test the latency of the virtual machine.The test result is on the below.

[the test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPcQ7.png)